# Return vue instance from vue.js filter (Vue.js 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using filter function for internationalization like this:

```
<div>{{ "hello" | message }}<div>
```

message is a filter function that depends on global Vue.config.lang variable.

It works great, but if I change Vue.config.lang, message doesn't rerender.

I wanted to make message rerender anytime Vue.config.lang changes, so I changed my filter function from

```
message => locale_messages[Vue.config.lang][message]
```

to

```
message => new Vue({
  template: '{{ message }}',
  computed: {
    message() { return locale_messages[Vue.config.lang][message]; }
  }
})
```

But it doesn't work. Getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (<anonymous>)
    ....
```

Is there anything I can do to make it work? I'm new to Vue.js and can't find a working solution.

Comment: In your position, I would try to dig into some of those components: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#i18n I think you can find some clue how you should work with i18n in Vue as I think you're doing it wrong...

Comment: Is now message a component? Can you provide a bit code around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Evan says, Filters should be [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), so thay can't use a global variable as key to get values from externals arrays. Because of side effects.

So, there is three solutions at your problem that comes in my mind :

- Replace filters by methods.
- Use [vue-i18-n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/), a simple and powerful module for translation
- Use a store system ([vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/)) wich provides you getters, and helps you manage a global state.

Personnaly I love to use vuex and vue-i18-n together.
In that way I can centralize my data and the language in use. I can also serve specific data in several languages using the store, and let vue-i18-n cares about all the strings in the project.

Answer (score 0):

New to Vue myself, so not quite sure how global variables work, but you can definitely pass params to a custom filter - even a Vue reference. You can do this:

```
<!-- this = a reference to the vue instance -->
<span class="display-3">{{value|FormatValue(this)}}</span>

[...]

props: ["aIsPercentNeeded"],

[...]

Vue.filter("FormatValue", function (aValue, aVueInstance)
{
  if (!aVueInstance["aIsPercentNeeded"])
  {
    return aValue;
  }

  return aValue + "%";
});
```